# Proving $x = y$ or $x = -y$ when $x^n = y^n$ and $n$ is even

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I'm currently going through Spivak's calculus, and after a lot of effort, i still can't seem to be able to figure this one out.

The problem states that you need to prove that $x = y$ or $x = -y$ if $x^n = y^n$

I tried to use the formula derived earlier for $x^n - y^n$ but that leaves either $(x-y) = 0$ or $(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ and i'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I can get from x-y = 0 that x = y but how can the longer form be reduced to say x = -y?

Comment: Hint: $x^{uv} - y^{uv} = (x^{u} - y^{u}) (x^{u(v-1)} + x^{u(v-2)} y^{u} + \dots + x^{u} y^{u(v-2)} + y^{u(v-1)})$.

Comment: Hint: you may reduce to the case when $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

Comment: $n=2k\Rightarrow x^{2k}-y^{2k}=(x^k+y^k)(x^k-y^k)=0$, if $k$ is odd you're done, otherwise continue saying $k=2k'$...

Comment: That's correct, but how do you properly express the notion of continuing to say $k = 2k'$?

Comment: Watch out for $n=0$. $n$ even and negative is OK.

Comment: Related: [Prove that if $x^{n} = y^{n}$ and $n$ is even, then $x = y$ or $x = −y$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471946)

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2p$. For convenience let us denote $y=a$. From the algebraic identities

\begin{eqnarray}
x^{2p}-a^{2p} &=&(x-a)\sum_{k=0}^{2p-1}a^{k}x^{2p-1-k}, \tag{1} \\
\sum_{k=0}^{2p-1}a^{k}x^{2p-1-k} &=&(x+a)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^{2k}x^{2p-2-2k},\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

we conclude that

\begin{equation}
x^{2p}-a^{2p}=(x-a)(x+a)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^{2k}x^{2p-2-2k}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Since for $a\neq 0$ the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^{2k}x^{2p-2-2k}$ on the right-hand side of (3) has no real
roots, it follows that the equation $x^{2p}-y^{2p}=0$ is equivalent to $(x-y)(x+y)=0$, thus proving that if $x^{n}=y^{n}$ and $ n $ is even, then $x=y$ or 
$x=-y$.

The identities $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be justified by applying [*Ruffini's Rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) twice: for identity $(1)$

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots  & 0 & 0 &  & -a^{2p} \\ 
a &    & a  & a^2 & \ldots  & a^{2p-2} & a^{2p-1} &  & a^{2p} \\ 
\hline
&   1 & a & a^{2} & \ldots  & a^{2p-2} & a^{2p-1} & | & 0
\end{array}
$$

\begin{equation*}
x^{2p}-a^{2p}=(x-a)(x^{2p-1}+ax^{2p-2}+a^{2}x^{2p-3}+\cdots
+a^{2p-2}x+a^{2p-1}),
\end{equation*}

and for identity $(2)$

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
 & 1 & a & a^{2} & a^{3} & \ldots  & a^{2p-2} &  & a^{2p-1} \\ 
-a &   & -a & 0 & -a^{3} & \ldots  & 0 &  & -a^{2p-1} \\ 
\hline
  & 1 & 0 & a^{2} & 0 & \ldots  & a^{2p-2} & | & 0
\end{array}
$$

$x^{2p-1}+ax^{2p-2}+\cdots +a^{2p-2}x+a^{2p-1}$
$$=(x+a)(x^{2p-2}+a^{2}x^{2p-4}+a^{4}x^{2p-6}+\cdots +a^{2p-4}x^{2}+a^{2p-2})$$

Answer (score 1):

The factorization of $x^k-y^k$ is known to be $(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+x^{k-3}y^2+\cdots y^{k-1})$, as you can verify by direct multiplication (all but two terms cancel in pairs).

Then $x^{2k}-y^{2k}=(x^2-y^2)(x^{2k-2}+x^{2k-4}y^2+x^{2k-6}y^4+\cdots y^{2k-2})$.

As all terms have an even exponent in the second factor, the latter cannot equal zero, and

$$x^{2k}=y^{2k}\iff x^2=y^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $x\mapsto x^n\colon \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is strictly increasing function and thus injective. Now,

$$x^n = y^n \implies |x|^n = |y|^n \implies |x| = |y| \implies x=\pm y\stackrel{\text{$n$ is even}}\implies x^n = y^n$$ therefore, $x^n = y^n\iff x =\pm y$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are assuming we are dealing with real numbers.  (The result is not true in complex numbers as $i^4 = 1^4 = (-1)^4  = (-i)^4$).

Now has it been shown to your satisfaction that every $b > 0$ has a unique positive $n-th$ root? Well... okay, let's do some basics

Okay, suppose $0 < |x| < |y|$ then $|x|^n < |y|^n$.  (And similarly if $0 < |y| < |x|)$.

[Because: if $|x| < |y|$ then $|x|^2 = |x||x| < |x||y| < |y||y| = |y|^2$ and inductively $|x|^{n-1} < |y|^{n-1} \implies |x|^{n-1}|x| < |y|^{n-1}|y|$]

Thus $|x|^n = |y|^n$ if and only if $|x| = |y|$.

Then as $x = \pm |x|$ and $y = \pm |y|$ so $x^n = (\pm 1)^n|x|^n$ (and same thing for $y^n$).

As $n$ is even $(\pm 1)^n = 1$.

So $x^n = y^n \iff |x| = |y| \iff x = \pm y$.

===

I haven't actually shown that if $b > 0$ that there actually *exists* an $x$ such that $x^n = b$.  But rereading the problem I see I don't have to.  The thing though is to realize if there *is* such a positive $x$ it is unique.  Which I can do by showing $x \ge \lt y; x>0;y>0 \implies x^n \ge \lt y^n$.

Comment: Hmmph... a comment mentions n = 0 and n < 0. n < 0 is fine as $x^n=y^n=> (1/x)^{|n|}=(1/y)^{|n|}$ and the same result follows. n=0 though $x^0=y^0=1$ always (except maybe x = 0) so it doesn't hold. –