# Proof: If $x^n = y^n$ and n is even, then $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

This is a problem from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1, Problem 6(d)

> Proof: If $x^n = y^n$ and n is even, then $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

I tried to prove it in the following way but I'm not sure if the proof makes sense, and the author uses another method.

Proof: Let $n=k+1$, $k$ is odd such that $x^{k+1}=y^{k+1}$. This would only be possible if $x^k=y^k$ or $x^k=-y^k$. This is because, if $x^k=y^k$ and $k$ is odd, then $x=y$ (I proved this on a previous exercise). Therefore, $x^k\cdot x = y^k \cdot x \Rightarrow x^{k+1}=y^{k+1}$.

Similarly, $x^k=-y^k \Rightarrow x=-y \Rightarrow x^{k+1}=y^{k+1}$. Thus, I have proved that $x^{k+1}=y^{k+1}$ is possible only if $x^k=y^k$ or $x^k=-y^k$. As I have already proved, $x^k=-y^k \Rightarrow x=-y$ and $x^k=y^k \Rightarrow x=y $

$\therefore x^n=y^n$ and $n$ is even $\Rightarrow x=y$ or $x=-y$

Comment: How do you know $x^k=\pm y^k$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $x^n = y^n$ and $n$ is even, then $x = y$ or $x = -y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471946/prove-that-if-xn-yn-and-n-is-even-then-x-y-or-x-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=2k$ be even and let $x^n =y^n$

We get $$x^{2k}=y^{2k}$$

Thus $$x^{2k}-y^{2k}=0$$

$$(x^2)^k-(y^2)^k=0$$

Factoring we get

$$(x^2-y^2)(x^{2k-2}+...+y^{2k-2})=0$$

That implies $$ x^2-y^2=0$$

Thus $$x=\pm y$$

Comment: How do I know that no more real solutions can be obtained from $(x^{2k-2}+...+y^{2k-2})=0$? Or is that not needed for this solution?

Comment: That expression is always positive unless $x=y=0$ (remember $x^n=y^n$)

Comment: How do you know $x^2 = y^2 \implies x =\pm y$?

Comment: It is true because $x^2-y^2=0$, then factoring we have $(x-y)(x+y)=0$. We conclude that $x-y=0$ or $x+y=0$, that is equivalent to $x=\pm y$.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, for your approach to work you'd need to first show $x^{n-1}=\pm y^{n-1}$. This will ultimately require an argument from moduli, such as the correct one below, rendering your technique unnecessary.

Taking moduli, $|x|^n=|y|^n$. Since $z\mapsto z^n$ is order-preserving on $[0,\,\infty)$, $|x|=|y|$. Therefore, $x=y$ or $x=-y$. The former works regardless of $n$'s parity; the latter works with nonzero variables for even $n$ only, since if $n$ is odd $(-x)^n=-x^n$.

(I'm assuming your variables are real. With complex numbers, counterexamples exist for even $n\ge4$, or even for odd $n\ge3$.)

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me.

If $0 \le x <  y$ then $x^n < y^n$.

Pf: By induction. Base case is $x < y$. Induction step is If we assume $x^{n} < y^{n}$ then $x^{n+1} = x*x^{n} < x*y^{n} < y*y^{n-1} = y^{n+1}$.

So if we know $x$ and $y$ are non negative and we are told $x^n = y^n$ then we know $x = y$. (By contradiction.  If $x \ne y$ then one is larger than the other and $x^n \ne y^n$)

Finally $(-x)^n = (-1*x)^n = (-1)^n x^n$ and $(-1)^n = 1$ if $n$ is even.  (Because $(-1)^{2k} = [(-1)^2]^k=1^k = 1$.)  So $(-x)^n = x^n$.

So.... we are ready:

If $x^n= y^n$ there are four cases:

1:  $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.  We've shown that means $x = y$.

2:  $x \ge 0$ and $y < 0$ then $-y > 0$ and $(-y)^n = y^n$ so $x^n = (-y)^n$ so $x = -y$.

3: $x < 0$ and $y\ge 0$.  Then $-x > 0$ and $(-x)^n=x^n = y^n$ so $-x = y$ and $x = -y$.

4) $x < 0$ and $y < 0$ then $-x>0$ and $-y > 0$ so $(-x)^n = x^n = y^n = (-y)^n$ so $-x =-y$ and $x = y$.

C'est tout.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill?

$y \not =0$.

$(x/y)^{2n}=1$, $n=1,2,.....$.

Set $z:=(x/y)$; then $z^{2n}=1$;

The $2n$ roots of unity are:

$z=e^{ik2π/(2n)}$, where $k=0,1,....,2n-1$.

Only $2$ real roots :

$k=0$: $z=1$, i.e. $x=y$ ;

$k=n$: $z=e^{-iπ} =-1$, i.e. $x=-y$.